# Wcf application can't open channel

Tags: .net, windows, wcf

I have simple Wcf application with client and host. Whole Wcf architecture is default, client logic is added by Visual Studio after adding Service Reference. Application worked fine for a long time and suddenly it stopped working today. During debuggin I saw, that the problem is, Client can't open the channel. There is no exception, debugger just doesn't enter next execution step. Host opens service as usually. I haven't change anything in the code. I tried writing new Wcf application and it didn't work for the same reason.

Google didn't help me. I'd appreciate any advise how to solve this problem. :)

Here is part of code of application I mentioned:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface iClientsQueries
{
    [OperationContract]
    resRegisterUser RegisterUser(reqRegisterUser request);
}
```

Client side:

```
public class ClientLogic
{
    User CurrentUser { get; set; }

    public ClientLogic(string phoneNumber)
    {

        client = new iClientsQueriesClient("WSHttpBinding_iClientsQueries");

        CurrentUser = new User() { PhoneNumber = phoneNumber, IsRegistered = true };
    }

    async public void RegisterUser()
    {
        var req = new reqRegisterUser() { QueryAuthor = CurrentUser };

        resRegisterUser res;

        try
        {
            res = client.RegisterUser(req);
            notFinished = false;    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            notFinished = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Host side:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class HostLogic : iClientsQueries
{

    public void StartHostng()
    {

        Uri hostAddress = new Uri(UriAddress);

        try
        {
            host = new ServiceHost(this, hostAddress);

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(iClientsQueries), new WSHttpBinding(), "TestService");

            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;

            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            host.Open();

            HostOn = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogsWriter.WriteExceptionLog(ex);
            HostOn = false;
            host.Abort();
        }
    }

    public void StopHosting()
    {
        if (host != null)
            host.Close();

        HostOn = false;
    }

    public resRegisterUser RegisterUser(reqRegisterUser request)
    {
        // LOGIC HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Very first thing that came to my mind is firewall is switched off?

Comment: @Fabjan , I tried switching off Antyvirus and Firewall. Unfortunetly, nothing has changed.

Comment: It looks like if something prevents client from opening channel to a server. But it's odd that that there is no exception thrown. Could you provide an example of your code please ?

Comment: @Fabjan, I added my code to the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when stuff like this happens is configure WCF message logging on both client and server and hope something comes up. In some cases the Windows Event log contains log entries that may help.

To configure WCF message logging you need to update your App.config file as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
      <listeners>
        <add name="messages"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging 
      logEntireMessage="true" 
      logMalformedMessages="false"
      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
      maxMessagesToLog="3000"
      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: This is how logs from client application look: [link](http://s15.postimg.org/4jtybi73f/serv.png). Can't read anything from that, looks like request has been sent. Server application hasn't created svclog file.